# Blank page after I open a link. I need to refresh to see the content

Tags: jquery, html

So I have a few HTML pages that I link between.

Let's say: 1. index.html links to page1.html and page1 links to page2.html

This is the header in my index.html and page1.html

```
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"/> 
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/date.js"></script>      
    <script src="js/leslider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.min.css" />    
    <script src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.core.min.js"></script>       
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.flipbox.min.js"></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://photoswipe.s3.amazonaws.com/pswp/dist/photoswipe.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://photoswipe.s3.amazonaws.com/pswp/dist/default-skin/default-skin.css'>
    <script src='http://photoswipe.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pswp/dist/photoswipe.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://photoswipe.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pswp/dist/photoswipe-ui-default.min.js'></script>
```

And this is my page2.html header

```
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://photoswipe.s3.amazonaws.com/pswp/dist/photoswipe.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://photoswipe.s3.amazonaws.com/pswp/dist/default-skin/default-skin.css'>
    <script src='http://photoswipe.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pswp/dist/photoswipe.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://photoswipe.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pswp/dist/photoswipe-ui-default.min.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../index.css" />
```

Im using JQ and JQM and some plugins and scripts as you can see; but I have no idea, why after I click on a link to grom from page1.html to page2.html the page should stay white until I refresh it manually.

Also, I can go back if I don't refresh the page (F5), but if I refresh the page it won't even go back to the previous document.

Comment: considering your page2.html header, it has some `js` files but you haven't included any `jQuery` library here, also a `JSFiddle` would be much helpful for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere, (*I DON'T REMEBER WHERE* - I'll update if I do) to just load the script in the body (on the page that wasn't loading), and actually that worked.